# Ajax Request not working. Doesn't get connected to server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've created a simple contact us form that captures data from textfields and then the data is converted to a JSON object and is being sent to the Server using Ajax. But I always gets the error. The success function isn't working. Which i believe that it doesn't get connected to the server.

Please tell me where I've gone wrong.

**HTML**

```
body>
  <h1> Contact Us </h1>
  We value your feedback. Send in your questions, suggestions, ideas to help us improve our service.

  <h2 align="Center"> Search us on Google Maps</h2>
<br> 
    <br>


    <form action="contact.php" name="form" method="post">

    <br>Name :<br>

    <input type="text" name="fName" id="fName"  required >

    &nbsp; &nbsp;
   <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName"  required >
    <br> <br>
    Email: <br>

    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required >

    <br> <br>
    Comment: <br>

    <textarea name= "comment" id = "comment" rows="8" cols="50"  ></textarea>

     <br> <br>

    Rate our Website <select name="select" id="select" >
    <option value = "1" name= "rate"> 1 </option>
    <option value = "2" name= "rate"> 2 </option>
    <option value = "3" name= "rate"> 3 </option>
    <option value = "4" name= "rate"> 4 </option>
    <option value = "5" name= "rate"> 5 </option>

    </select>

     <br> <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">

  </form>
  </body>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("form").submit(function(){
        alert("Submitted");

        var jsonArr = {
          firstName   :document.getElementById("fName").value,
          lastName    :document.getElementById("lName").value,
          email       :document.getElementById("email").value,
          comment     :document.getElementById("comment").value,
          rate        :document.getElementById("select").value
        };


          $.ajax({
              url       : "contact.php",
              type      : "POST",
              data      : JSON.stringify(jsonArr),
              dataType  : "json",
              success   : function(data){
                console.log("This is working", data);
              },
              error     : function (error){
                alert("Error. not working"+ error);
                console.log("Error. not working" , error);
              }

          });

    });

});

 </script>
```

**PHP**

```
<html>
    <body>
    <?php
    $decode = $_POST['firstName'];
var_dump($decode);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please notice that you didn't closed your `php` code in the `contact.php` file - therefore, the php file prints an error and your jscript can't access it.
Fix: `var_dump($decode); ?>`

Another thing - learn to use **FireBug or Chrome Console**, under `network tab` you can really learn and understand what's going on.

Comment: You also should place the error inside the alert -> alert("Error: " + error);

Comment: I've corrected everything but all i'm getting is Notice: Undefined index: firstName in C:\xampp\htdocs\contact.php on line 5
NULL

Comment: @AkilaRandil There are more problems...

Answer (score 1):

First, try adding a slash to your url to make it relative to your host:

```
    $.ajax({
          url       : "/contact.php",
          type      : "POST",
          data      : JSON.stringify(jsonArr),
          dataType  : "json",
          success   : function(data){
            console.log("This is working", data);
          },
          error     : function (error){
            alert("Error: " + error);
            console.log("Error. not working" , error);
          }

      });
```

And second, close your PHP tag in the contact.php file:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <?php
    $decode = $_POST['firstName'];
var_dump($decode);
</body>
</html>
```

should be:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <?php
        $decode = $_POST['firstName'];
        var_dump($decode);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've corrected everything but all i'm getting is Notice: Undefined index: firstName in C:\xampp\htdocs\contact.php on line 5
NULL

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues here:

**Cancel default submit**

You are not cancelling the default submit event so the form will get submitted the non-ajax way, effectively reloading the page (assuming that everything is done on `contact.php`).

You need something like:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
});
```

**Send the type of data that is expected on the server**

You are not sending data to the server in a format that will allow you to access it through `$_POST`. You are sending a string so to get to that, you would need to read the input. If you want to access it through `$_POST` you need to send a query string or (better as they are encoded automatically...) an object. The easiest way to get your encoded data is using:

```
...
data: $('form').serialize(),
...
```

or, if you want to use your set keys:

```
...
data: jsonArr,  // sending an object is fine, jQuery will encode it correctly for you
...
```

**PHP syntax error**

Your php has syntax errors as mentioned before. However, that is irrelevant here because of the next problem.

**Return only json from your php script**

The biggest problem with your php is that it returns html and not json. As you have set:

```
dataType  : "json",
```

your php script needs to return valid json. So no tags, or any echoes except for a single `json_encode()`.

So for your example, it should contain only:

```
<?php
$decode = $_POST['firstName'];
// do some more stuff?

echo json_encode($decode);
exit;
```

Comment: @AkilaRandil What you want to return to the success function in jQuery. So an (nested...) array or object containing all information you need. In the success function it will be available as a javascript object, just try `console.log(data)`. If you want to return text or html, you would need to remove `dataType  : "json",`.

Comment: I want as a JSON. But i get this error in my console. "Error. not working parsererror". Bascially what needs to be done is that the data should be put into a JSON object and should be sent to the PHP and then the data should be extracted.

Comment: @AkilaRandil No, it is the other way around, data should be sent to the php as key-value pairs and the php script should return a json string.

Comment: oh okay. i understand now. but the thing i can't really figure out is that the success function is not working. how should i fix that? i've been doing various types of methods for the last 4 days and still haven't figured out the problem.

Comment: @AkilaRandil As long as you combine `dataType : "json",` with a php script that does not output 100% valid json (and nothing else...), you will never get to your success function. You should remove `dataType : "json",` at least temporarily to see what happens.

Comment: I removed it and the success function is working. but neither the alerts are working when the dataType is removed. and the server side is till not reading and data from the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your JS (see below). Trigger onclick event, and prevent default from possible duplicate submisssions and restructure your json. See if this works.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "contact.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    'firstName': document.getElementById("fName").value,
                    'lastName ': document.getElementById("lName").value,
                    'email': document.getElementById("email").value,
                    'comment': document.getElementById("comment").value,
                    'rate': document.getElementById("select").value
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("This is working", data);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert("Error. not working") + error;
                    console.log("Error. not working", error);
                }

            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: You *should* bind to the `submit` event instead of the `click` event, since forms can be submitted without clicking the button at the end.

Answer (score -1):

add an id attribute to form and try this code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("form").submit(function(){
        alert("Submitted");




          $.ajax({
              url       : "contact.php",
              type      : "POST",
              data      : $("{formid}").serialize,

              success   : function(data){
                console.log("This is working", data);
              },
              error     : function (error){
                alert("Error. not working")+ error;
                console.log("Error. not working" , error);
              }

          });

    });

});

 </script>
```

Comment: Why would this make a difference?

Comment: first of all this will remove lots of code send this will send dropdown selected value to server too.